# The home_switch function keeps returning that there is no screen with name "home"

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import sqlite3
from kivymd.uix.fitimage import FitImage

Window.size = (360, 780)

class Start_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class Sign_Up(Screen):

    def signup(self):
        signup_password = self.signup_password.text
        signup_password_re = self.signup_password_re.text

        if signup_password != "" and signup_password_re != "":
            if signup_password == signup_password_re:
                print ("correct")
                sm.home_switch()

            else:
                print ("incorrect")
        else:
            print ("empty")

class Log_In(Screen):
    pass

class Home(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):

    def home_switch(self, *args):
        self.current = "home"

sm = WindowManager()

class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Yellow"

        return Builder.load_file('Vocate.kv')

MainApp().run()
```

and this is the .kv file

```
WindowManager:

    Start_Screen:
        name: "start"

    Sign_Up:
        name: "sign up"

    Log_In:
        name: "log in"
    Home:
        name: "home"



<Sign_Up>:
    name: "sign up"
    id: signup
    signup_phone: signup_phone
    signup_password: signup_password
    signup_password_re: signup_password_re

    MDFloatLayout:
        Image:
            source: 'images/Vocate.png'
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.6
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.2, "center_y": 0.95}

        FloatLayout:
            cols: 1

            MDTextField:
                id: signup_phone
                hint_text: "Phone Number"
                required: True
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: 0.9, 0.09
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.725}
                multiline: False

                helper_text: "This Field is Required"
                helper_text_mode: "on_error"

            MDTextField:
                id: signup_password
                hint_text: "Password"
                required: True
                password: True
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: 0.9, 0.09
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.625}
                multiline: False

                helper_text: "This Field is Required"
                helper_text_mode: "on_error"

            MDTextField:
                id: signup_password_re
                hint_text: "Password"
                required: True
                password: True
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: 0.9, 0.09
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.525}
                multiline: False

                helper_text: "This Field is Required"
                helper_text_mode: "on_error"

            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                md_bg_color: 250/255, 205/255, 62/255, 1
                font_size: 20
                text_color: 254.99/255, 255/255, 255/255, 1
                size_hint: 0.9, 0.06
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.425}
                text: "Sign Up"
                bold: True

                on_release:
                    root.signup()

            MDFlatButton:

                text: "Go Back"
                bold: True
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: 250/255, 205/255, 62/255, 1
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: 0.9, 0.06
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.34}

                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "start"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

<Home>:
    name: 'home'

    MDFloatLayout:
        cols: 1
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

            MDBottomNavigation:

                MDBottomNavigationItem:
                    name: "home screen"
                    icon: "home"

                    MDBoxLayout:
                        orientation: "vertical"

                        MDToolbar:
                            title: "Home"
                            md_bg_color: 250/255, 205/255, 62/255, 1
                            specific_text_color: 255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 1

                        MDLabel:
                            text: "test 1"
                            halign: "center"

                MDBottomNavigationItem:
                    name: "courses"
                    icon: "book-open-variant"

                    MDFloatLayout:
                        cols: 2

                        MDBoxLayout:
                            orientation: "horizontal"

                            MDBoxLayout:
                                orientation: "vertical"

                                MDToolbar:
                                    md_bg_color: 250/255, 205/255, 62/255, 1

                                FitImage:
                                    source: "images/coding.png"

                                FitImage:
                                    source: "images/python.png"

                                FitImage:
                                    source: "images/gsuite.png"

                                FitImage:
                                    source: "images/english.png"

                                FitImage:
                                    source: "images/vocate.png"

                                FitImage:
                                    source: "images/vocate.png"

                            MDBoxLayout:
                                orientation: "vertical"

                                MDToolbar:
                                    md_bg_color: 250/255, 205/255, 62/255, 1

                                MDLabel:
                                    text: "Coding - 1"

                                MDLabel:
                                    text: "Coding - 2"

                                MDLabel:
                                    text: "Gsuite"

                                MDLabel:
                                    text: "English"

                                MDLabel:
                                    text: "Woodworking"

                                MDLabel:
                                    text: "Customer Service"

                        MDBoxLayout:
                            orientation: "vertical"

                            MDToolbar:
                                title: "Courses"
                                md_bg_color: 250/255, 205/255, 62/255, 1
                                specific_text_color: 255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 1

                            Button:
                                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

                            Button:
                                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

                            Button:
                                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

                            Button:
                                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

                            Button:
                                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

                            Button:
                                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

                MDBottomNavigationItem:
                    name: "more"
                    icon: "dots-horizontal"

                    MDBoxLayout:
                        orientation: "vertical"

                        MDToolbar:
                            title: "More"
                            md_bg_color: 250/255, 205/255, 62/255, 1
                            specific_text_color: 255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 1

                        MDLabel:
                            text: "test 3"
                            halign: "center"
```

I've tried changing "WindowManager:" to "" but it returns a blank screen. Some questions similar to this I've seen say to remove the builder and rename the file so I've tried "Main.kv" and "MainApp.kv" and both return the same blank screen.

Thanks in advance!

*Note: I've removed some of the code so that it's clearer so some of the screens and some other stuff that won't interfere here aren't included

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the line `sm = WindowManager()` is creating the `WindowManager` before the `Vocate.kv` file is loaded. As a result, the `sm` has no `Screens`.

A way to fix that is to eliminate the `sm = WindowManager()` line completely, and use the `manager` property of a `Screen` to access the `WindowManager`. Like this:

```
class Sign_Up(Screen):

    def signup(self):
        signup_password = self.signup_password.text
        signup_password_re = self.signup_password_re.text

        if signup_password != "" and signup_password_re != "":
            if signup_password == signup_password_re:
                print ("correct")
                self.manager.home_switch()  # use manager property

            else:
                print ("incorrect")
        else:
            print ("empty")
```

Comment: Ah thanks a ton man i was breaking my head over this for a while but it works now